# No Wi-Fi options on HP 450 g3 i7 with Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: networking, drivers, 15.04, hp

I just bought a new [laptop](http://www8.hp.com/pk/en/products/laptops/product-detail.html?oid=7834555) HP ProBook 450 G3 Notebook PC i7, and installed `Ubuntu 15.04` on it, but after installation it's not giving me any options for connecting with Wi-Fi. I have tried every possible solution available on Stack Overflow and the Internet.

Kindly update me with the possible solution or may I switch to [Ubuntu 14.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_14.04_LTS_.28Trusty_Tahr.29) (Trusty Tahr) or another version to get it working properly?

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:3165] (rev 81)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:4010]
```

PS: When I don't do anything on the system, and leave it alone, it goes to sleep, but on moving the mouse it just blinks again and again with the login screen. Why is it so?

Comment: You tried "every possible solution" without even knowing the adapter model?  ;-)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Okay sorry am doing it wait a sec

Comment: And why do you install 15.04 that will reach eol in 4 days?

Comment: which should i install?

Comment: The supported versions are 14.04 LTS and 15.10. I recommend 14.04.3. But it is not related to your wireless problem. Give output of the command and I will give you directions how to fix  it.

Comment: where is your comment? @Pilot6

Comment: I removed it and wrote an answer.

Comment: Only ask ONE question per question. Your system is not going to sleep, it's just the screensaver blanking your screen because you're not using it (no kbd/mouse events for a while), the screensaver is asking you to show that you ARE you before unblanking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest installing Ubuntu 14.04.3.

After you install the system, connect to internet by wire and upgrade the kernel by running:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-wily
```

Wi-Fi should work after reboot.

Ubuntu 14.04.4 will support this adapter out-of-the-box. It will be released soon. You do not need to deliberately upgrade to it. Just install regular updates.

Comment: Okay thanks :) i will update after doing it and that blinking issue is because of?

Comment: This is another issue. If it persists on the new system, then you are welcome to ask another question.

Comment: i am installing it just want to tell you that while installing it , on startup it showed some notification as `iwlwifi`  failed.

Comment: It is OK. After you upgrade the kernel it should work

Comment: Hi @Pilot6 can i have you on this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/732685/no-sound-on-ubuntu-14-04-3-lts