# No sound on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

Tags: 14.04, drivers, sound, pulseaudio

I have installed `Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS`. first it wasnt working for Wifi Drivers then after asking here i sorted that out now Sound Drivers arent working properly. already tried [Solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457619/sound-not-working-in-ubuntu-14-04)  and this [Solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/469804/ubuntu-14-04-no-sound).

PLUS after doing this solution i have nothing left in my WHOLE settings. 
Language Support,Updates and 2 other. EVERY setting has gone?

Comment: Seems that something is really messed up. Have you tried to use Ubuntu 15.10? It has newer kernel, if you have some fancy and exotic hardvare, wifi and sound  support should be better.

Comment: Settings are back now. just tell me the solution of sound now

Comment: What are output of "sudo dmidecode" and "lspci" commands in terminal? Put that on http://pastebin.com/ and post link here. Try 15.10 livecd too, you don't have to install that, just test.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/89ugND9h here it is. i cant switch versions i have a lot of burden installed on this version now.

Comment: See answer below.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No sound on Ubuntu 15.10](http://askubuntu.com/questions/700167/no-sound-on-ubuntu-15-10)

Comment: its 15.10 and i have 14.0.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that you have solution for your hardware here:
[No sound on Ubuntu 15.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/700167/no-sound-on-ubuntu-15-10)

> I found the solution (!), create a new file /etc/modprobe.d/intel.conf
>
> add the following options:

```
options snd-hda-intel single_cmd=1
options snd-hda-intel probe_mask=1
```

> reboot....